# Convertir formato de columna de un df en R

Tags: r, lista, dataframe

Tengo el siguiente df:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que busco es crear un nuevo dataframe donde por cada grupo de TIMESTAMP y CUSTOMER.ZONE se repita tantas veces tenga el vector de la métrica asociada, por ejemplo la primera fila debe quedar así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
.
.
.
y así con todas la filas del df...

He intentado con:

```
df2 <- data.frame(t(lapply(df,c)))
df2 <- data.frame(t(sapply(df,c)))
df2 <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, df))
df2 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, df))
df2 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, df))
```

pero sin lograr lo esperado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo un `data.frame` similar al tuyo:

```
df <- data.frame(TIMESTAMP=c(1,2,3),
                 CUSTOMER_ZONE=c('A', 'B', 'C'),
                 metrica=t(rbind(list(c(1,3,1,7,3), c(1), c(6)))))

  TIMESTAMP CUSTOMER_ZONE       metrica
1         1             A 1, 3, 1, 7, 3
2         2             B             1
3         3             C             6
```

Una forma muy sencilla es usar [`unnest()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.3/topics/unnest)

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  unnest(metrica)

# A tibble: 7 x 3
  TIMESTAMP CUSTOMER_ZONE metrica
      <dbl> <fct>           <dbl>
1         1 A                   1
2         1 A                   3
3         1 A                   1
4         1 A                   7
5         1 A                   3
6         2 B                   1
7         3 C                   6
```

Sino, la versión R base, adaptada de [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31195925/unpacking-and-merging-lists-in-a-column-in-data-frame):

```
do.call('rbind', 
        lapply(1:nrow(df), 
               function(x) data.frame(TIMESTAMP = df[x, 1],
                                      CUSTOMER_ZONE = df[x, 2],
                                      metrica = unlist(df[x, -c(1,2)]), 
                                      row.names = NULL)
               )
        )
```

Comment: Gracias Patricio por el aporte, era lo que buscaba una función clara y sencilla.